# Testing WeakReference

Tags: java, unit-testing, weak-references

What is the proper approach to testing a weak reference in Java?

My initial idea is to do the following:

```
public class WeakReferenceTest {

    public class Target{
        private String value;    

        public Target(String value){
            this.value = value;
        }    
        public String toString(){
            return value;
        }
    }

    public class UsesWeakReference{    
        WeakReference<Target> reference;   

        public UsesWeakReference(Target test){
            reference = new WeakReference<Target>(test);
        }    
        public String call(){
            Target test = reference.get();
            if(test != null){
                return test.toString();
            }
            return "empty";
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testWeakReference(){    
        Target target = new Target("42");

        UsesWeakReference usesWeakReference = new UsesWeakReference(target);    
        WeakReference<Target> triggerReference = new WeakReference<Target>(target);    
        assertEquals("42", usesWeakReference.call());

        target = null;    
        while(triggerReference.get() != null){
            System.gc();
        }

        assertEquals("empty", usesWeakReference.call());    
    }    
}
```

The reservation I have about the approach is using System.gc(), as I understand that it can behave differently on different JVMs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no 100% bombproof way of testing code that uses the Reference types.  The behaviour of Reference objects depends on when the GC runs, and there is no 100% reliable way of forcing the GC to run.

The best you can do is:

- check that you have the right JVM options set when running the tests, and
- write your test so that it doesn't fail in the event that `System.gc()` is a no-op **OR** be willing to disable or skip the test, or ignore the test failure.

(You should be able to detect that `System.gc()` is being ignored by looking at how much memory is in use before and after the call; e.g. by calling `Runtime.totalMemory()`)

---

Actually, there is another "solution".  Have your unit test generate a huge amount of garbage ... enough to guarantee that you will trigger garbage collection.  (Not a good idea, IMO.)

Answer (score 5):

New answer to old question; I found your question as I am dealing with the exact same problem: I want to write a unit test in order to verify that my class under test does something very specific if the referent of a WeakReference turns null.

I first wrote a simple test case that would set the referent to null; to then call `System.gc()`; and interestingly enough: at least within my eclipse, that was "good enough" for my `weakRefernce.get()` to return null.

But who knows if that will work for all the future environments that will run this unit test for the years to come.

So, after thinking some more:

```
@Test
public void testDeregisterOnNullReferentWithMock() {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    WeakReference<Object> weakReference = EasyMock.createStrictMock(WeakReference.class);
    EasyMock.expect(weakReference.get()).andReturn(null);
    EasyMock.replay(weakReference);
    assertThat(weakReference.get(), nullValue());
    EasyMock.verify(weakReference);
}
```

Works nicely, too.

Meaning: the generic answer to this problem is a factory that creates WeakReference for objects for you. So, when you want to test your production code; you provide a mocked factory to it; and that factory will in turn mocked WeakReference objects; and now you are in full control regarding the behavior of that weak reference object.

And "full control" is much better than *assuming* that the GC maybe does what you hope it is doing.

Comment: Mocking is best here, as GC is not perfectly deterministic nor controllable.

Comment: Very correct - I added another paragraph to make that more clear. For the record: is there anything else I could do to make this upvote worthy in your eyes?

Comment: I think it is already quite clear. I had to create another constructor for my type I want to test to provide a mocked WeakReference (is a constructor primarily for testing clean code? ;)). Maybe it is noteworthy, that mocking the WeakReference is best for reproducible tests but less "realistic", meaning if you want to explicitly test unreliable GC behavior it is maybe not the best approach. (thanks for the upvote ;))

Comment: Well. You can use another constructor (which I would make package protected); or when using Mockito, there is the @InjectMocks annotation (which I personally do not use, as it fails silently - so you never know if your mocks were really injected).

Answer (score 0):

I want to piggyback off of GhostCat salutes Monica C's answer which says to use mocks. This is certainly one route, however while implementing this I noticed there is actually a `clear()` function on `WeakReference` itself. So rather than doing the heavy lifting of creating the mocks you can create a factory instance and simply clear the referent yourself. The approach I used is written in Kotlin so hopefully the syntax isn't too jarring, but this is exactly what I have.

Our Factory looks like this, you can think of the `invoke()` function as a constructor, functionally that's what it is doing, practically it saves us from implementing a class for the default behavior.

```kotlin
interface WeakReferenceFactory {
    fun <T> create(referent: T): WeakReference<T>

    companion object {
        // Allows us to create a production ready instance with WeakReferenceFactory(), avoids having to implement a concrete instance.
        operator fun invoke(): WeakReferenceFactory {
            return object : WeakReferenceFactory {
                override fun <T> create(referent: T): WeakReference<T> {
                    return WeakReference(referent)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For our tests we can then implement the Factory with an additional `clear()` function, doing so allows us to keep a reference of the instance we are using in a test and then simply pass it into the factory to be cleared.

```kotlin
class WeakReferenceFactoryFake : WeakReferenceFactory {
    private val managedReferents = mutableListOf<WeakReference<*>>()

    fun <T> clear(referent: T) {
        managedReferents.filter { it.get() == referent }
            .forEach { it.clear() }
    }

    override fun <T> create(referent: T): WeakReference<T> {
        val weakReference = WeakReference(referent)
        managedReferents.add(weakReference)
        return weakReference
    }
}
```

Then within your test you would have something like this (sorry for the Foo's and Bar's).

```kotlin
class FooTest {
    private val fakeWeakReferenceFactory = WeakReferenceFactoryFake()

    private val subject: Foo = Foo(fakeWeakReferenceFactory)

    @Test
    fun `given foo, when bar is cleared, then bar should be null`() {
        val bar = Bar()
        foo.put(bar)

        fakeWeakReferenceFactory.clear(bar)

        assert(bar).isNull()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Came across a similar issue today.

TLDR solution:  Extend WeakReference and override .get()

---

Was trying to use mockk to mock out `WeakReference<*>` like this:

```
val weakRef = mockk<WeakReference<String>>()

@Test
fun testWeakRef() {
   every {weakRef.get()} returns "apple"
   // ... etc, etc
}
```

However, I then get a

```
Missing mocked calls inside every { ... } block: make sure the object inside the block is a mock
```

Not sure yet why mockk doesn't like to mock WeakReference.

So instead, just extend the class **within your test directory.**

```
class MockWeakReference<T>(initialValue: T? = null) : WeakReference<T>(null) {

    private var mockValue = initialValue

    override fun get(): T? {
        return mockValue
    }

    fun setMockValue(value: T?) {
        mockValue = value
    }
}
```

and then instead of using `every` or `when`, just use `mockWeakRef.setMockValue($x)`